# How to write certain criteria into a text file from a binary file

Tags: java, binaryfiles

I have developed a method that will extract all data from .data file and write them into a text file

```
myTextFile = new PrintWriter(
                    new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("file.txt")));
            input = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("file.data")));



  //This loop will take all info found in file.data but what if I want only where country is USA for exemple 
            while (input.available() > 0) {

                countryNumber = input.readInt();
                population = input.readInt();
                region = input.readUTF();
                State = input.readUTF();
                loan = input.readInt();
                categorie = (input.readChar());
                adresse = (input.readUTF());
                descrpt = input.readUTF();
            //Now I  print all info from file.data to file.txt
       myTextFile.println(region.toString() + " " + population.toString() + " " + region + " " + State + " " + categorie + " " + loan + " " + adresse);

            }
 myTextFile.close();
            input.close();
```

As you can notice , I make a loop `While(imput.available()>0` that will take all data found in the file.data and write everything into text file

But what if I want to write in the text file only where region = NewYork ? and write the population, state etc.... of new york in the text file ?

is their any way I can limit criteria ?

Much appreciation,

Bass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do such thing is to allocate a fixed amount of bytes to each record by record I mean the tuple countryNumber, population, region, State, loan, categorie, adresse and descrpt. Then you put the value of your region as first value of your record this way you can read the region, check if it is the expected region and if so you can stop reading the file otherwise you go directly to the next record and so on.

This approach allows you to read only sub parts of the file instead of reading everything which is more optimal.

Comment: It's actually one of the best optimal approach , I will try it thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

Before writing you might just add an if-statement checking if region.equals("NewYork").
That would be:

```
if(region.equals("NewYork")) myTextFile.println(region.toString() + " " + population.toString() + " " + region + " " + State + " " + categorie + " " + loan + " " + adresse);
```

Comment: This might really really work , will try it out thanks!!